# Python opens executable, but it doesn't close on its own

Tags: python, executable

Little background: Code::Blocks is an IDE with a C++ integrated compiler. When creating a C++ project, it creates a .exe file so you can run the project.

So now I want to run that executable file using a Python script (Using VSCode). I tried subprocess.call(), subprocess.run() and subprocess.Popen(), and all of them start the background process, but it doesn't compile, so it just keeps running on the Task Manager. If I run it manually (by double-clicking it) then it opens, it closes and I get my correct answer on the output file.

[This is the C++ project folder for the problem "kino" :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBpS1.png)

[This is a photo with the .exe on the Task Manager :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJwka.png)

And this is my Python code:

```
process = subprocess.run([r'C:\Users\Documents\kino\kino.exe'], shell = True)
```

If you still don't understand my problem, [here is a video describing it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTbmA.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved my problem was by running the executable using the ./ command. So, I did something like

```
process = subprocess.run('./kino.exe', shell = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pywin32 to get it done.
Something like this will solve your issue

```
import win32com.client
 app = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
 app.Run('Path/Yourexe.exe')
```

Comment: This made the executable pop up and not run in the background, however it stays open and runs, with no result on the output file.

Comment: Well you can add app.quit() to close it and see if it solves the problem. Otherwise share your code for better understanding

Comment: It doesn't seem to work either. [I posted another video too see how it behaves](https://imgur.com/a/rEFVo51)
The text in the notepad file should be replaced with the number 7.

Answer (score 0):

`subprocess.run` would not capture the output of the spawn process, however there is no reason for it to keep running in background. Try the following example, I just checked this in my linux(with a simple 'hello world' program) so if it does not works for you then it could be OS specific issue.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['C:\Users\Documents\kino\kino.exe'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
#out, err = p.communicate()
print(p.stdout.read())
```

Comment: It might be some OS specific issue. I use windows, and, as previously, the executable just runs in the background, having to close it manually.